# Rails File.exist? yields false when file is present

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've found a few posts here regarding File.exists? in a Rails app but trying the solutions have not helped, I'm fairly new so I must be doing something dumb.

I'm using:

- Rails 3.2.11
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Paperclip for the file mentioned below
- ActiveAdmin to upload the file mentioned below
- Working in development environment
- Assets not precompiled

I have a model "style" and it has an image attachment, I can render the image with

```
<%= image_tag(@style.style_image) %>
```

and it works just fine.

In short, I want to check if the file image is actually there in the folder it should be in - I don't want to use **@style.style_image.present?** for checking images because that just checks the db record. I want to use **File.exist?** to see if there's actually a file for **@style.style_image**.

So in my view file, I have the code

```
<% if File.exist?(@style.style_image.url) %>
The image exists.
<% else %>
The image is not here.
<% end %>
```

And it always prints "the image is not here" when I load the page. Directly below I am displaying my image using image_tag, so I know for fact that the image is there.

I've also tried

```
<% if File.exist?(Rails.root + @style.style_image.url) %>
```

with no luck. I also tried using FileTest.exist?, FileTest.exists?, and File.exists? but none will tell me true when the image is definitely there.

Is there something I'm missing? Any guidance would be appreciated very much. I'm only a few months into Ruby and Rails so I'm probably missing something dumb.

Comment: You need to pass a path to `File.exist?` not a url.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't have a higher rating for this question. Well asked. +1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want `@style.style_image.path` instead of `.url`.

Print it out to be sure.

Comment: You two were right, thanks! Also I made an error, style_image is another model, and style_image.image is the actual image. So the solution that worked is `<% if File.exist?(@style.style_image.image.path) %>`

Comment: @TomNetzband Sure, glad I could help. Mark the answer as correct to help out anyone else who might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Any time you are dealing with web URLs and files on disk, you have to be careful which "path" you are using, and keep it straight whether you are telling your code to where to find the file, or a browser how to request that same file.

The web server hides the OS's file structure from the user/browser for lots of reasons, with security being a very high one. For instance, URLs are relative to the server, not the root of the drive.

What you ran into is very common and odds are really good that everyone who is working with programming for the web has, or will, run into the same thing, probably several times.